# Sum of first rows of the year in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

How to achieve such a result in column C?

[image: What I want in Excel]

The column C should automatically determine first row in a year by column "A", take a corresponding value from column "B" and then in each row of column "C" make a sum only of those first-in-a-year entries of column "B" as listed.

I am stuck at the following step:

```
=MIN(A1:A23-DATE(YEAR(A3);1;1))
```

Here is the data in text form to help reproducing the case:

```
23.01.2018 19:04    7000
07.06.2018 17:38    7000
08.06.2018 19:59    7000
06.09.2018 20:20    7000
19.10.2018 21:42    7000
15.11.2018 17:21    7000
16.11.2018 19:04    7000
20.11.2018 17:56    7000
09.12.2018 23:25    7000
01.01.2019 20:44    12000
10.03.2019 21:20    12000
24.06.2019 17:46    12000
05.07.2019 19:40    12000
28.08.2019 18:03    12000
27.09.2019 16:46    12000
01.11.2019 17:15    12000
11.11.2019 20:03    12000
24.01.2020 18:49    12000
13.03.2020 18:37    12000
24.04.2020 17:41    12000
06.05.2020 19:09    12000
07.10.2020 21:20    12000
04.12.2021 17:17    12000
```

Comment: Hint: in `C2`, for example, you could go `=IF(Year(A2)<>Year(A1),B2,"")`. This will return column B only if the current row's year is different from the previous. (Not really a programming question though... more of "how to use Excel")

Comment: What is your excel version. Also put few data text table so that we can copy.

Answer (score 0):

the first row in C column =B2
for the second row =IF(YEAR(A2)<>YEAR(A3),C2+B3,C2)
then drag the second row for the rest of the table.